# Black background in the bounding box created when an image is rotated with PHP

Tags: php, transparency, image-rotation, bounding-box

I've scoured the internet in search for an answer to this, but I cannot seem to find something that works. When I rotate an image, say, 5 degrees, that image is rotated within a boundary image that is created to house the rotation. That created image is completely black.

I'm trying to make it so that the bounding box image is completely transparent.
Some of the other websites and questions I've looked at say that this should work:

```
<?PHP
$png = imagecreatefrompng('polaroids/polaroid0002.png');

// Do required operations
$png = imagerotate($png, 354.793, 0, 0);

// Turn off alpha blending and set alpha flag
imagealphablending($png, false);
imagesavealpha($png, true);

// Output image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($png);
imagedestroy($png);
?>
```

However, that yields this:

[image: yields]

What can I do for the black bounding box to be transparent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a transparent colour `imagecolorallocatealpha($png, 0, 0, 0, 127)` for background color.

```
<?php
$png = imagecreatefrompng('polaroids/polaroid0002.png');

// Do required operations
$png = imagerotate($png, 354.793, imagecolorallocatealpha($png, 0, 0, 0, 127), 0);

// Turn off alpha blending and set alpha flag
imagealphablending($png, false);
imagesavealpha($png, true);

// Output image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($png);
imagedestroy($png);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I am not familiar with using that particular PHP function. That said, most developers seem to prefer directly using ImageMagick or GD for image processing with PHP. The function your using seems to be a GD function. I would start looking here. You may have to modify the image resource a bit more to set transparency or a different color.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

I recommend looking at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php

Comment: This script uses GD. I haven't seen any tutorials out there which use ImageMagick.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I jumped the gun and modified the answer a second ago.

Comment: Tried adding this:
`$black = imagecolorallocate($png, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($png, $black);` before the header part and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that WORKS (dug it up from my 3 year old archives). I used it to combine 2 png images and render some text, while keeping transparency. It creates a new image, sets the transparency color, then copies the images into it. This exact file worked on my implementation (the colors however I've made up right now, because back then I was extracting them from a database so I have no memory what they were and what they meant). Sorry if it's messy. The resulting image is `$image`, which is composed of `$ruler_img` as the first layer, `$index_img` as the second layer, and text as the third layer. You only have one layer in your case.

```
        //prepare first layer
        $ruler_img=$ruler_img=imagecreatefrompng($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$ruler['out_ruler_img']);
        //create main image, basic layer, background
        $image = imageCreateTrueColor($ruler_width, $ruler_height);
        imageSaveAlpha($image, true);
        $transparentColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0,0,0, 127); //some color used as transparency key, this uses black
        $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0,0,0,127);
        //fill with transparent color
        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparentColor);

        imagealphablending($ruler_img,true);
        //copy the first layer
        imagecopy($image,$ruler_img,0,0,0,0,$ruler_width,$ruler_height);

        //prepare the second layer 
        $index_img=imagecreatefrompng($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$ruler['out_index_img']);
        $size=getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$ruler['out_index_img']);
        $index_width=$size[0];
        $index_height=$size[1];

        imagealphablending($index_img,true);

        $ratio=1.0;
        if($index_height>$ruler_height)
            $ratio=$ruler_height*1.0/$index_height;
        $new_width=$index_width*$ratio;
        $new_height=$index_height*$ratio;

        //now I copy the resampled second layer 
        imagecopyresampled(
            $image,
            $index_img,
            $position*($ruler_width-$new_width),
            ($ruler_height-$new_height)/2,
            0,
            0,
            $new_width,
            $new_height,
            $index_width,
            $index_height);
        //render text   
        $font = "fonts/comic.ttf";
        $fontSize=10;
        $box=imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font,$text);
        $textWidth=$box[2]-$box[6];
        $textHeight=$box[3]-$box[7];

        imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $ruler_width-$textWidth-10, $ruler_height+12, $color, $font, $text);
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        //that's it!
        imagepng($image);
```

Comment: Very interesting implementation. Trying this.

Comment: I have decided to go with the simpler solution posted above. Thanks though.